# stop powershell with keypress

Tags: powershell, administrator

How can I stop Powershell by pressing a key. I have a loop, which should be stopped, when I press "q". How to do that.

I have found the following code, but didn't work

```
while($true) {
    Write-Host "Working" -BackgroundColor Green

    if($Host.UI.RawUI.KeyAvailable -and ("q" -eq $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("IncludeKeyup,NoEcho").Character)) {
        Write-Host "Exiting now, don't try to stop me...." -BackgroundColor DarkRed
        break;
    }
}
```

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the same code works, but not in PowerShell ISE but in the normal PowerShell console. You guys have to save it if you are scripting and then execute via Powershell console.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the same for PowerShell ISE?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit the program itself you could use `Ctrl+C` and it will stop the script.
You could be more specific, that if you have some code to run after the loop, in that case this wont work.

Comment: I am going to have a GUI attached to my script. That's why I need to specify sth that could be connected with a button in the GUI and if it is pressed, the whole programme(link. GUI & Script) should be stopped.

Comment: instead you connect it with a variable and use a while loop